# How to hide unexpected Python "splash" window that displays before my MainWindow in pyside6

Tags: qt, pyside6, qsplashscreen

Before my QMainWindow appears on screen, a smaller window titled "Python" opens up for about half a second.

I tried adding self.hide() at the top of the MainWindow **init** (just after super().**init**()), but that had no effect.  I also tried covering it up with a QSplashScreen, but the window appears on top of the splash screen.  Is there any way to prevent this unexpected "Python" window from appearing? [Unexpected "Python" window screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g56mh.png)

Here's my main file splashtest.py:

```py
import sys
from modules.gui.main_window import *

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    #pixmap = QPixmap('./breadware-splash.png')
    #splash = QSplashScreen(pixmap)
    #splash.show()
    window = Window()
    #splash.finish(window)
    app.exec()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is main_window.py:

```py
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTabWidget, QSplashScreen
from PySide6.QtGui import QPixmap
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, QSize, QThread, QObject, Signal
from modules.gui.test_tab import *

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        parent = super().__init__()

        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle('Breadware Test')

        # Create a tab widget
        self.tw = QTabWidget()
        self.testtab = self.tw.addTab(TestTab(self), "Test Device")
        self.tw.show()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tw)
        self.show()
```

And here is test_tab.py:

```py
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QTextEdit, QGridLayout

class TestTab(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()

        self.parent = parent

        grid = QGridLayout()
        
        self.infoarea = QTextEdit(self) 
        self.infoarea.setReadOnly(True)
        self.infoarea.setStyleSheet("background-color: black; border: 0;")
    
        grid.addWidget(self.infoarea, 5, 1, 1, 2)

        self.setLayout(grid)
        self.show()

        self.infoarea.insertHtml("<span style=\"font-size:12pt; font-weight:800; color:white;\" >Hello There</span><br>")
```

Comment: You probably created another widget for the wrong reason. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: I added sample code to replicate the problem.  I noticed that if I remove the tab widget, the spurious window displays for a shorter period of time, but it still shows.  By the way, this is under windows 10 running Python 3.9.10

Comment: For future reference, either use the 4-spaces indentation or the three ticks (\`\`\`) code fence, not both (read more about [formatting code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362)); check my edit to see the difference. Also, unless the issue is related to the usage of multiple files, try to merge the code in a single "file block" instead of using splitted files or snippets. This is to make us easier to reproduce your code instead of being distracted on making it run in the first place: the easier you make us to check your code, the easier it is to answer you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### tl;dr

Remove `self.tw.show()` from `Window` and `self.show()` in `TestTab`.

### Explanation

As a rule of thumb, `self.show()` should **never** be called in the `__init__()` of a widget, especially for widgets that are going to be "reparented" (it becomes a *child* of another widget).

In your case, you are doing that mistake twice:

- the first time, implicitly, in the `__init__()` of `TestTab` as written above;
- then, again, in the `__init__()` of `Window`, *before* setting it as a central widget, which has the same result, because you are showing it before reparenting it;

<sup>Note: calling `show()` (just like `setVisible(True)`) more than once within the same function call does not change the result; with your current code, even using just *one* of the calls above would have created the issue, as you experience showed, based on your comment); such calls are not immediate, the create an extended *queue* of events that eventually result in what the user can see and interact with on the screen. If the widget is already visible, any further call is a no-op, *unless* another change in the widget status has happened in the meantime, such as changing the [window flags](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowFlags-prop).</sup>

The reason is simple: if a widget is created without a parent, it is always considered a top level one (a *window*). If a widget that has no parent calls `self.show()`, it will show itself as a separate window.

Your code would not have created the issue *if*:

- you did not call `self.tw.show()` before `self.setCentralWidget()`;
- most importantly, you *properly* used the `parent` argument of `__init__()` by calling `super().__init__(parent)` (because you used `TestTab(self)`);

Calling `show()` on a child widget will (obviously) not show it if the parent is not shown, it will only "mark" it as visible and make it as such as soon as the parent is shown. This is extremely important for child widgets created *after* the parent is being shown: in that case, calling `show()` is mandatory (unless the widget is added to the layout manager of the parent, see below).

This means that the only cases for which calling `self.show()` in the init is considerable acceptable is:

- when you are completely sure that the widget will always be a top level window;
- when the `parent` argument is properly used in the super call *and* the parent is actually valid:

```
class ProperShowCallWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        if parent is not None:
            self.show()
```

The above will make the widget automatically visible when it's created with a parent, even if it is not going to be added to a layout manager.
Be aware that, actually, you should always use layouts managers (unless you **really** know what you are doing), so calling `show()` is pointless, as a child widget is implicitly shown when added to a widget layout, *unless* `setVisible(False)` (or `hide()`) is explicitly called.

So, not only you should remove those `show()` calls as written at the beginning of this post, but you should also remove `self.show()` in the `__init__()` of `Window` and move it into your "main" code:

```py
def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec()) # <- you should use sys.exit()
```

**Do *not* underestimate the documentation**

I strongly advise you to take your time to carefully study the related documentation for:

- the [`visible`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#visible-prop) property;
- [`isHidden()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#isHidden) (which is *not* the same as `not isVisible()`);
- [`isVisibleTo()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#isVisibleTo);
- [`window()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#window) and [`isWindow()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#isWindow);
- the [`Qt.WindowFlags`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#WindowType-enum) (notably, `Qt.Window`, automatically set for any widget created without a parent);
- [`parentWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#parentWidget), [`QObject.parent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#parent) and the concepts behind Qt [object trees and ownership](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/objecttrees.html);
- the ***whole*** documentation about [QWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html) and the inherited [QObject](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html) type, starting from their detailed description, going through all their functions, and then doing the same for all the related classes used by those functions;

Finally, consider that there are always exceptions. There *are* widgets that, even if created with a parent, are still shown as top level widgets. The most common case is QDialog (and all its subclasses, such as QMessageBox), which is always considered a top level window by default, even if it has a parent widget. That is because they are [modal windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window), and the parent widget is used as a *reference* to know to what window they are considered modal (blocking any input to those windows until the dialog is closed). Other similar cases are: menus, tooltips, floating tool bars/dock widgets and splash screens (see the `Qt.WindowFlags` above: they all use a window flag that uses the `Qt.Window` enum).