# Spline Editor in PyQt5 QGraphicsView

Tags: python, pyqt5, spline, qgraphicsview

I'm trying to do a spline editor where the knots are movable points that define a spline (calculated each time the points move). I have a code using Tkinter working perfectly:

```
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate as si


class LineEditorApp:
    def __init__(self, rooty):
        self.root = rooty
        self.root.title("Line Editor App")

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(rooty, width=400, height=400)
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.points = [self.create_movable_point(x, 200) for x in [120, 170, 220, 270]]

        self.line = None
        self.point_lines = []
        self.update_line()

    def create_movable_point(self, x, y):
        point = self.canvas.create_oval(x - 5, y - 5, x + 5, y + 5, fill="red")
        self.canvas.tag_bind(point, "<Button1-Motion>", lambda event, point=point: self.move_point(event, point))
        return point

    def move_point(self, event, point):
        x, y = event.x, event.y
        self.canvas.coords(point, x - 5, y - 5, x + 5, y + 5)
        self.update_line()

    def update_line(self):
        if self.line:
            self.canvas.delete(self.line)

        if self.point_lines:
            for line in self.point_lines:
                self.canvas.delete(line)

        # Get coordinates x and y of all points
        x_coords = [self.canvas.coords(point)[0] + 5 for point in self.points]
        y_coords = [self.canvas.coords(point)[1] + 5 for point in self.points]

        # Calcula uma spline B-spline com base nos pontos
        degree = 3  # Grau da spline B-spline
        spline_points = bspline(list(zip(x_coords, y_coords)), degree=degree)

        # Crie a linha para seguir a spline
        line_coords = [(int(x), int(y)) for x, y in spline_points]
        self.line = self.canvas.create_line(line_coords, fill="blue", width=2)

        # Crie linhas pretas finas entre pontos consecutivos
        self.point_lines = []
        for i in range(len(self.points) - 1):
            x1, y1 = self.canvas.coords(self.points[i])[0] + 5, self.canvas.coords(self.points[i])[1] + 5
            x2, y2 = self.canvas.coords(self.points[i + 1])[0] + 5, self.canvas.coords(self.points[i + 1])[1] + 5
            line = self.canvas.create_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="black", width=1)
            self.point_lines.append(line)


def bspline(cv, n=100, degree=3):
    """ Calculate n samples on a B-spline

        cv :      Array of control vertices
        n  :      Number of samples to return
        degree:   Curve degree
    """
    cv = np.asarray(cv)
    count = cv.shape[0]

    # Prevent degree from exceeding count-1, otherwise splev will crash
    degree = np.clip(degree, 1, count - 1)

    # Calculate knot vector
    kv = np.array([0] * degree + list(range(count - degree + 1)) + [count - degree] * degree, dtype='int')

    # Calculate query range
    u = np.linspace(0, (count - degree), n)

    # Calculate result
    return np.array(si.splev(u, (kv, cv.T, degree))).T


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = LineEditorApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Now the challenge is changing this to PyQt5, as I will need some functions of the QGraphicsView widget later on. The code is almost working as I need, the problem is that the points and the line are not corresponding. I'd appreciate any help. This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate as si
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QObject
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPen, QBrush


class EventFilter(QObject):
    def __init__(self, app):
        super().__init__()
        self.app = app

    def eventFilter(self, watched, event):
        if watched == self.app.scene:
            if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.GraphicsSceneMouseMove:
                self.app.update_line()
        return super().eventFilter(watched, event)


class LineEditorApp:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.root.setWindowTitle("Line Editor App")

        self.canvas = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.root)
        self.canvas.setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 500)

        self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
        self.canvas.setScene(self.scene)

        self.points = [self.create_movable_point(x, 200) for x in [120, 170, 220, 270]]

        self.line = None
        self.point_lines = []
        self.update_line()

        self.root.show()

        self.event_filter = EventFilter(self)
        self.scene.installEventFilter(self.event_filter)

    def create_movable_point(self, x, y):
        point = self.scene.addEllipse(x - 5, y - 5, 10, 10, QPen(Qt.red), QBrush(Qt.red))
        point.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        point.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges)
        point.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
        point.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsScenePositionChanges)
        point.setZValue(1)
        point.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)
        point.setAcceptDrops(True)
        point.setAcceptTouchEvents(True)

        point.setPos(x, y)

        return point

    def update_line(self):
        if self.line:
            self.scene.removeItem(self.line)

        if self.point_lines:
            for line in self.point_lines:
                self.scene.removeItem(line)

        # Get coordinates x and y of all points
        x_coords = [point.scenePos().x() + 5 for point in self.points]
        y_coords = [point.scenePos().y() + 5 for point in self.points]

        degree = 3
        spline_points = bspline(list(zip(x_coords, y_coords)), degree=degree)

        line_coords = [(int(x), int(y)) for x, y in spline_points]

        # Create a continuous line connecting the spline_points
        line_path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        line_path.moveTo(*line_coords[0])
        for coord in line_coords[1:]:
            line_path.lineTo(*coord)

        self.line = self.scene.addPath(line_path, QPen(Qt.blue, 2, Qt.SolidLine))
        self.line.setZValue(0)

        # Create black lines connecting the control points
        for i in range(len(self.points) - 1):
            x1 = self.points[i].scenePos().x() + 5
            y1 = self.points[i].scenePos().y() + 5
            x2 = self.points[i + 1].scenePos().x() + 5
            y2 = self.points[i + 1].scenePos().y() + 5
            point_line = self.scene.addLine(x1, y1, x2, y2)
            point_line.setPen(Qt.black)
            point_line.setZValue(0)
            self.point_lines.append(point_line)

        self.scene.update()

def bspline(cv, n=100, degree=3):
    """ Calculate n samples on a B-spline

        cv :      Array of control vertices
        n  :      Number of samples to return
        degree:   Curve degree
    """
    cv = np.asarray(cv)
    count = cv.shape[0]

    # Prevent degree from exceeding count-1, otherwise splev will crash
    degree = np.clip(degree, 1, count - 1)

    # Calculate knot vector
    kv = np.array([0] * degree + list(range(count - degree + 1)) + [count - degree] * degree, dtype='int')

    # Calculate query range
    u = np.linspace(0, (count - degree), n)

    # Calculate result
    return np.array(si.splev(u, (kv, cv.T, degree))).T


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = LineEditorApp()
    app.exec_()
```

Question short: How can I put the movable points in the same spot as the points that define the spline (end-points of the black lines in this picture):

PyQt5 code result

[image]

I expect something like this:

Tkinter code result

[image]

Comment: There are some important issues with your implementation, mostly: 1. you're never removing deleted points from the list (but you're still trying to remove them from the scene); 2. most importantly, you're constantly and unnecessarily creating new items. QGraphicsScene is not a simple drawing canvas: graphics items are *persistent* and should not be removed and added again every time. Also, it seems clear that you're not considering relative coordinates. Functions like `addLine` **always** create the item at `0, 0`, so their *visual* origin is not the same as their scene (or parent) position.

Comment: I strongly suggest you to take a look at the [Graphics View](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html#the-graphics-view-coordinate-system) documentation, especially the part related to the coordinate system. Simply put, when you create an item using the base functions like `addEllipse()`, the *position* of the item is ***NOT*** the visual position of the drawn object: `addEllipse(20, 20, 20, 20)` will show an ellipse at `20, 20`, but its position will still be at `0, 0`. If you need to use the visual position as reference, you have to create it with reference `0, 0` and *then* call `setPos(20, 20)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach has several issues, but the following two are the most important:

- you are not considering relative coordinates (where items are drawn is always relative to the item *position*);
- new items are constantly created and removed even when it is absolutely unnecessary, while they could and should be *reused* instead;

### The coordinate system

The first aspect is fundamental: when items are added to a scene, their positions are **always** initialized at coordinates `0, 0`, and all the contents of each item are always relative to its origin point. This is valid for any item, including those created with the convenience functions like `addLine()` or `addEllipse()`.

This may seem unintuitive, but it's appropriate if you think about it.

If you use `scene.addRect(10, 0, 10, 10)` you would think that it would create a QGraphicsRectItem that is *placed* at `10, 0`, showing a `10x10` square at those coordinates.

Now, consider the case of QPainterPath, in which many different objects can be added; for example, you add two squares: `path.addRect(10, 0, 10, 10)` and `path.addRect(0, 10, 10, 10)`. Then, you add that path to the scene with `addPath()`, which would create a QGraphicsPathItem; what would be the *position* of that item: `10, 0` or `0, 10`? And why would it be the former instead of the latter (or vice-versa)?

In reality, it is always `0, 0`, even for the `addRect()` above, which is *placed* at `0, 0`, but *shows* the square at `10, 0`. If you then move (set the position with `setPos()`) the item to `10, 0`, that will be its real position: the square will be *shown* at `10, 10` in scene coordinates, but if you try to use the getter function of the item's rectangle, you will still get its *origin* at `10, 0` ([`rect.topLeft()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrectf.html#topLeft)).

This is also what the documentation reports for all those functions, such as [`addEllipse()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#addEllipse):

> Note that the item's geometry is provided in item coordinates, and its position is initialized to (0, 0).

Your problem is caused by the fact that you are creating the "points" by *also* adding their coordinates in the constructor, but then again you call `setPos()` with those coordinates, which is not correct: the appropriate approach, in this case, is to create the "point ellipse" around its origin point (aka, `0, 0`) and *then* call `setPos(x, y)` with the real coordinates for that point; since you probably want the points being shown at the center of their origin (so that you can use their position as reference), the final rectangle should be created "around" it, with the `x` and `y` equal to negative half of their dimension; `x` and `y` will exactly be at a value that is a negative of the half of the corresponding ellipse axes, and since we're doing a circle, that means that they will both be a negative of half the diameter, which is the negative radius:

```py
    def create_movable_point(self, x, y):
        point = self.scene.addEllipse(-5, -5, 10, 10, QPen(Qt.red), QBrush(Qt.red))
        ...
        point.setPos(x, y)
```

In this way, whenever a "control point" is moved, you can know for sure that its position always corresponds to the actual coordinates you need for that point.

A further and important note, before going on: item positions are **always** relative to their parent. If they have no parent, they are "top level items", so their "parent" is the scene, and their position is relative to it. In your current code, each "control point" is actually a top level item, and since their parent is actually the scene itself, their `pos()` is the same of their `scenePos()`. If, instead, those items were children of another item, their position would have been relative to their parent.
I strongly suggest you to carefully read the documentation about the [Graphics View Coordinate System](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html), and also do proper research about the [Cartesian coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) upon which the Graphics View Framework is based.
Fundamentally speaking, this is the same as widget coordinates: the `geometry()` of a widget is always relative to its parent, so if a widget is a top level one (aka, a *window*), its geometry is relative to the "scene" (aka, the overall available geometry of all screens). That's the reason for functions like `mapTo` and `mapFrom`, which exist for Qt widgets just like QGraphicsItems (and QGraphicsScene/View).

### Item creation

Now, the other problem is that you're constantly trying to recreate the straight lines that connect control points, but that's not appropriate for a case like this: unless the number of control points changes, you should always try to *reuse* existing line items.

The Qt Graphics View is not like basic painting canvases, which directly draw primitives on drawing surfaces: objects are persistent and should always be reused unless their removal is necessary.

Most importantly, you're always adding the new line elements to the `point_lines` list, but you never remove them from that list when you actually remove the items, which results in the following output:

```
QGraphicsScene::removeItem: item 0x91e3a50's scene (0x0) is different from this scene (0x909aa70)
```

This means two things:

- each item creation and removal potentially causes a full computation and repainting of *anything* within the scene, but also further unnecessary aspects, like item collisions, event handling or general item checks for items that are simply being destroyed;
- the `point_lines` list grows on and on, for **any** mouse movement, easily increasing the element count (and to the order of thousands!) which means that you fundamentally have a memory leak;

This brings us to a final issue: movement detection.

### Putting everything together

Right now you are doing all the above for any mouse movement, which is clearly unnecessary, since the user may just move the mouse over the scene without changing absolutely anything.

For a case like this, where there is a strict relation between multiple elements, it's always better to use a common parent for items that are part of the same "group". In your case, a possible approach is to make a QGraphicsPathItem subclass that will represent the whole curve, which *contains* child items: a QGraphicsPathItem for the straight connection lines, and different QGraphicsEllipseItems for each control point.

Then, in order to update the curve only when the control points are moved, we can "detect" position changes and consequentially update the curve.

In the Qt world this is normally achieved by signals (possibly custom ones), but in this case it's not possible, since only QObject subclasses can have signals, and basic QGraphicsItem primitives do not inherit from it.

A possible workaround for this is to use QGraphicsObject subclasses that have the *actual* item as their child, but in this specific case we can avoid it and implement a pseudo-signal behavior:

```py
class PseudoSignal(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.connections = []

    def connect(self, func):
        self.connections.append(func)

    def disconnect(self, func):
        if func in self.connections:
            self.connections.remove(func)

    def emit(self, *args):
        for func in self.connections:
            try:
                func(*args)
            except Exception:
                traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)


class ControlPoint(QGraphicsEllipseItem):
    def __init__(self, pos, parent):
        super().__init__(-5, -5, 10, 10, parent)
        self.setPos(pos)
        self.setPen(QPen(Qt.red))
        self.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.darkRed))
        self.setFlags(
            QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable
            | QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsScenePositionChanges
        )
        self.moved = PseudoSignal()

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if change == QGraphicsItem.ItemPositionHasChanged:
            self.moved.emit()
        return super().itemChange(change, value)
```

<sup>Note that the above `PseudoSignal` is declared as an instance attribute, unlike standard Qt signals which **must** be created at class level. Also, since it's not a *real* Qt signal, it should be used with care. The above implementation is just a simplification of the concept.

Note that this can theoretically be done more easily by just passing the reference to the target function to the item constructor, and then call that function within `itemChange`, but the above approach is more appropriate, considering important OOP aspects such as the [*separation of concerns*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), and trying to keep consistency with the overall signal/slot mechanism of Qt.</sup>

Then, the spline class actually implements the curve update on its own, which is far better, since with this you can even create multiple curves on the same scene.

```py
class SplinePath(QGraphicsPathItem):
    def __init__(self, points=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.setPen(QPen(Qt.blue, 2, Qt.SolidLine))
        self.lineItem = QGraphicsPathItem(self)

        self.controlPoints = []
        if points is not None:
            self.setPoints(points)

    def setPoints(self, points):
        scene = self.scene()
        while self.controlPoints:
            cp = self.controlPoints.pop()
            cp.setParentItem(scene)
            if scene:
                scene.removeItem(cp)

        for p in points:
            cp = ControlPoint(p, self)
            self.controlPoints.append(cp)
            cp.moved.connect(self.updateCurve)

        self.updateCurve()

    def updateCurve(self):
        if len(self.controlPoints) <= 1:
            self.setPath(QPainterPath())
            self.lineItem.setPath(QPainterPath())
            return

        first = self.controlPoints[0]
        linePath = QPainterPath(first.pos())
        points = [(first.x(), first.y())]
        for cp in self.controlPoints[1:]:
            linePath.lineTo(cp.pos())
            points.append((cp.x(), cp.y()))
        self.lineItem.setPath(linePath)

        curvePoints = bspline(points)
        curvePath = QPainterPath(QPointF(*curvePoints[0]))
        for x, y in curvePoints[1:]:
            curvePath.lineTo(x, y)
        self.setPath(curvePath)
```

Now, the `LineEditorApp` is actually a standard python object, and it's not really necessary to use such basic classes as "main" classes in a context like this.
And, technically speaking, you already have an "app" (the QApplication instance), so the naming is also ambiguous.

If you need a "controller", for instance to manage multiple windows, it's normally better to subclass the QApplication instead, since it's guaranteed that only one instance of it will (or, at least, should) ever exist.

Also, the "root" widget (the top level window) has no layout manager set, meaning that if you resize it, the graphics view will not adapt to it.

Instead, just create a subclass of QWidget (or directly QGraphicsView if you don't need other widgets in the same window) and access it accordingly:

```py
class LineEditorWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Line Editor App")

        self.canvas = QGraphicsView()
        self.canvas.setRenderHints(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.canvas.setScene(self.scene)

        self.spline = SplinePath((x, 200) for x in (120, 170, 220, 270))
        self.scene.addItem(self.spline)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.resize(500, 500)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window = LineEditorWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

<sup>Note that I moved the `show()` call outside of the `__init__()`, as calling it in there is normally discouraged (see [this partially related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75431775/2001654)).</sup>

And here is the final result:

[image: Screenshot of the example code]